# no output from process when using combine and map

Tags: nextflow

I'd be interested in sending pair of files, in my case they are tumor-normal.

In the code below there's no output from align process. No lines/output are shown from the align process.

```
process align {
   debug true 
        input:
        tuple val(sampleid),path(tumorSamples),path(normalSamples)
        
        output:
        stdout

        script:
        """
        echo "we are all good ${tumorSamples} ${sampleid} \n"
        """
}

workflow {
        tumorSamples = Channel.fromFilePairs('/sc/arion/projects/test_input_data/MM-*-tumor-*.fastq.gz')
        normalSamples = Channel.fromFilePairs('/sc/arion/projects/test_input_data/MM-*-normal-*.fastq.gz')


tumorSamples
        .combine(normalSamples)
        .map { tumorSample, normalSample -> tuple(path(tumorSample), path(normalSample))}
        .set { pairedSamples }
        
//pairedSamples.view()

align(pairedSamples).view()   

}
```

In the directory I've tumor sample as: MM_sample1_tumor_R1.fastq.gz, MM_sample1_tumor_R2.fastq.gz and normal sample as: MM_sample1_normal_R1.fastq.gz, MM_sample1_normal_R2.fastq.gz

Similarly, other samples.

How do I capture MM_sample1 in `sampleid` variable as I send my paired-tumor-normal files?

Second, I'd like to see paired files, however, `pairedSamples.view()` generates no output.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that the fromFilePairs Channel-Factory does not find your filepairs. It seems like nextflow does not like two separate asterisks in the pattern. In this case I would suggest you work over the expression and be more specific about your file pattern expected (`MM_*_tumor_R{1,2}.fastq`).

```
tumorSamples = Channel.fromFilePairs("test/MM_*_tumor_R{1,2}.fastq.gz")
normalSamples = Channel.fromFilePairs("test/MM_*_normal_R{1,2}.fastq.gz")

tumorSamples .view()
```

which creates this output:

```
[MM_sample1, [/path/to/test/MM_sample1_tumor_R1.fastq.gz, /path/to/test/MM_sample1_tumor_R2.fastq.gz]
```

Now you already have the same value at pos 0 of your tuples for both channels and instead of using `.combine` I think the `.join` method is what you actually want to do:

```
tumorSamples.join(normalSamples).view()
```

Afterwards your channel is perfectly formatted for your defined process and should look like this:

```
[MM_sample1, [/path/to/test/MM_sample1_tumor_R1.fastq.gz, /path/to/test/MM_sample1_tumor_R2.fastq.gz], [/path/to/test/MM_sample1_normal_R1.fastq.gz, /path/to/test/MM_sample1_normal_R2.fastq.gz]]
```